# Putting on hold until OP clarifies some of the questions in the comments

Tags: discussion

Travel Stack Exchange.
comment     Aug 30 at 0:04
Seat aisles blocked by baggage

'Putting on hold until OP clarifies some of the questions in the comments'.

How am I supposed to clarify the questions (which seem quite clear to me) when the post/topic is locked?

I have largely answered them myself and maybe others would like to know the answers?

Comment: This is about this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/142966/seat-aisles-blocked-by-baggage

Answer (score 6):

> How am I supposed to clarify the questions (which seem quite clear to me) when the post/topic is locked?

By editing the question, or perhaps by posting comments on the question.  Both are possible when a question is on hold or closed.  That only prevents the posting of new *answers.*

Comment: No it was not possible. Whatever I did I got the answer that the question was on hold.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited in the 'answer' you posted here and re-opened that question.

Answer (score -2):

1. By way of example of what is normally required, the US FAA Advisory Circular Carry-On Baggage which provides information on how to comply with carry-on baggage regulations (AC121-29A, page 2, Par5) says that the FAA could approve a carry-on baggage program that requires baggage stowed under a seat not to project beyond the overhanging seat. It says  ... ensure that each piece of baggage fits under the seat such that no part of the bag protrudes bey0nd the fully upright seat back or causes obstruction to passenger movement to, from, or across the aisle'.
2. As another example, the Lufthansa Terms and Conditions  -  General Conditions of Carriage state at 8.7.1 Baggage you carry onto the aircraft must fit under the seat in front of you ... The airlines own diagrams and even the tags attached to carry on bags show such a bag entirely under (ie NOT sticking out) the seat as the FAA prescription above.
3. National aviation safety agencies such as the FAA or CASA (Australia, with whom I have discussed this issue) have no authority over other nation's airlines. Thus a complaint  to the UK CAA cannot be dealt with by it and has been referred to the German Luftfahrt-Bundesamt section responsible airline licensing and cabin-crew inspection.
4. Following are some pictures from the flight in question
   [image]

[image]